# How to play MPEG-4 multicast streaming on VLC

Tags: windows, streaming, vlc, multicast, mpeg-4

I want to play MPEG-4 Part 2 multicast streaming on VLC, but can not.

MPEG-2 and H.264 multicast streaming was able to play.

How can I play it?

- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit
- VLC Version: 2.2.4
- Command: vlc -I dummy -vvv udp://@{MulticastAddress}:{Port}

Logs:

```
[007fb7e4] core stream debug: received first data after 5699 ms
[007fb7e4] core stream debug: prebuffering done 1164 bytes in 5s - 0 KiB/s
[007fb884] core stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 6 candidates
[007fb884] core stream debug: no stream_filter modules matched
[007fbec4] core stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 6 candidates
[007fbec4] core stream debug: using stream_filter module "record"
[00824bec] core input debug: creating demux: access='udp' demux='any' location='@{MulticastAddress}:{Port}' file='\\@{MulticastAddress}:{Port}'
[0080bb0c] core demux debug: looking for demux module matching "any": 66 candidates
[0080bb0c] ts demux debug: Force Seek Per Percent: PCR's not found,
[0080bb0c] ts demux warning: lost synchro
[0080bb0c] ts demux debug: skipping 16 bytes of garbage
[0080bb0c] ts demux debug: pid[4113] unknown
[0080bb0c] ts demux warning: lost synchro
[0080bb0c] ts demux debug: skipping 12 bytes of garbage
[0080bb0c] ts demux warning: lost synchro
[0080bb0c] ts demux debug: skipping 12 bytes of garbage
[0080bb0c] ts demux warning: lost synchro
[0080bb0c] ts demux debug: skipping 12 bytes of garbage
[0080bb0c] ts demux warning: lost synchro
[0080bb0c] ts demux debug: skipping 12 bytes of garbage
[0080bb0c] ts demux debug: pid[256] unknown
[0080bb0c] ts demux debug: pid[4097] unknown
[0080bb0c] ts demux warning: lost synchro
[0080bb0c] ts demux debug: skipping 12 bytes of garbage
[0080bb0c] ts demux warning: lost synchro
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is your source encoder? & are you sure your multicast is working?

Comment: I just heard only with the "MPEG-4 stream", and got the captured packets. multicast is working.

Comment: I dont understand 'I just heard only with the "MPEG-4 stream"' - I'll have a check on my decoders when I get into work as we use VLC & encode our own mcast services

Comment: You are right. I have just checked it again, encoder is Fujitsu IP-700II.

Comment: I've just checked my encoder - its only encoding MPEG2. I need to have a look at another unit as I *think* I had an issue with MPEG4 and a CCTV network so I need to try and find some very old notes. There was all sorts of settings on the encoder I had to change to get it to play nice with our system